riddle: requestAnimationFrame in iframes call back more frequently the more iframes there are (in chrome)
I build visual art with TypeScript and WebGL. Sometimes, artworks get embedded as iframes.
I have noticed some animations running faster when multiple artworks are embedded as iframes on a page.
I checked and realized that the rate at which requestAnimationFrame calls back increases with the amount of artworks added as iframes.
I recreated a minimal example:
FPS with 1 iframe:

FPS per iframe with 2 ifames:

Here is the html of the page that contains two times the same "artwork" as an iframe:
<body>
    <div id="stack-container">
        <div class="wrapper" style="opacity: 0.51; z-index: 0;"><iframe src="https://gfx.aimparency.org/controllable/fps/"></iframe></div>
        <div class="wrapper" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 1;"><iframe src="https://gfx.aimparency.org/controllable/fps/"></iframe></div></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts?t=1722986133016"></script>
    ...
</body>


The frame rate per iframe increases even more with 3 or 4 iframes and so on. To be clear: this is not the sum of frame rates - this is each iframe running at a higher speed the more sibling iframes there are on the website.
This leaves me puzzled - even more, when I realized that it makes a difference, whether I embed artworks from my server or from my local dev server. When embedding multiple artworks that are served by a local vite dev server started with npm run dev, the artworks have the expected frame od around 60Hz.
Here is the minimal "artwork" just showing the FPS.
import './style.css'

import { 
  Clock
} from 'time-n-controls';

class Loop {
  clock = new Clock()

  fpsElement = document.getElementById('fps') as HTMLParagraphElement

  constructor() {

  }

  start() {
    this.loop() 
  }

  private loop() {
    this.clock.tick()

    this.fpsElement.innerText = this.clock.getTickSmoothFPS().toFixed(2)

    requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this))
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  const loop = new Loop()
  loop.start()
}

If you think Clock might be the issue, here is the relevant code:
  // tick shall be called once per frame, especially for tickDelta
  private smoothFPS = 0
  private previousTick = Date.now()
  tick() {
    const now = Date.now()
    this.tickDeltaMS = now - this.previousTick
    this.tickDeltaS = this.tickDeltaMS * 0.001
    this.previousTick = now

    this.smoothFPS = this.smoothFPS * 0.9 + 0.1 / (this.tickDeltaS + 0.001)

    this.update()
    this.notifyQueues()
    this.updatedDynamicTimes(this.tickDeltaS)
  }

  getTickSmoothFPS() {
    return this.smoothFPS
  }


I would expect every artwork embedded as an iframe to run with 60Hz but the rate increases with every iframe added.
I have a hunch that requesting animation frames from multiple iframes makes the browser call all iframes requestAnimationFrame callbacks for every iframe - but only when coming from the same https source - that's why there is the difference with the dev server vs. prod.
I hope some expert can shed light on this and also I'm looking for a clean way to keep the framerates reasonable within each iframe! :)
Thanks!
Edit:
Oh, I should mention my browser:
Chromium 126.0.6478.182 Arch Linux
I just checked and firefox does not expose this weirdness :)

Looks like they don't clear the list of same cross-origin documents after they process it, which would lead to a double update of every cross-origin frames that do share the same origin with another frame that called requestAnimationFrame. It is obviously a bug and as such should be reported.
To be noted: iframes that are same-origin with their embedder doc do not expose this behavior.
Also, it's a regression, apparently caused by something in that list. I see you opened this report, let's see how it goes.
As for a workaround, you should anyway be using the delta time to drive your animation since different users will have different frame rates. You can thus just ignore the frames where the delta is almost zero. If you take the timestamp that's passed to the callback, or even document.timeline.currentTime (these are the same), then you can even filter out the ones that are exactly zero.
